# Can't figure out how to make my menu button work when in mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, responsive

I'm trying to learn and make my navigation responsive from scratch and I'm stuck in making the menu button work. By it working means when I click the menu-icon, the menu would slideDown like in most websites we see. I've checked and tried to learn the method from W3Schools but I'm not able to apply it here. Can anyone help me **make it only with the existing html** and not add extra html code. I know it can be done but I'm new in this and can't seem to do it. Help! :)

P.S. The code for menu-icon turning into an 'X' is written in JavaScript because I'm unable to turn it into jQuery. Would prefer jQuery more. Thanks :)

Here's the link : https://codepen.io/selate/full/yvvyzz/

```
<html>
...all html code here.(in CodePen)
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by make the menu button 'work'?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish when you click the menu button?

Comment: By it working means when I click the menu-icon, the menu would slideDown like in most websites we see.

Answer (score 0):

To change your vanilla js function into jquery, it would look something like this:

```
$('.menu-icon').on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('change'); //add the class change to the element clicked
     $('.header-list').toggleClass('open'); //adds a new class to the menu list
});
```

You can also add a class to your menu list then define the css to display it properly.  I give a very basic example.  You'll have to mess around with it to make it look nice.

Here is the relevant css that I changed to make the menu list display on click on mobile:

```
.header-list {
    display: none;
}

.header-list.open {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 400px;
    background: beige;
}
```

I also removed this event handler since we now are using jquery to do the same thing.

`<div class="menu-icon" onclick="menuFunction(this)">`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.menu-icon').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('change');
    $('.header-list').toggleClass('open');
  });

  $(function() {
    $('.header-logo h2').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.faq-list-item').click(function() {
      var $answer = $(this).find('.answer');
      if ($answer.hasClass('open')) {
        $answer.removeClass('open');
        $answer.slideUp();
        $(this).find('span').text('+');
      } else {
        $answer.addClass('open');
        $answer.slideDown();
        $(this).find('span').text('-');
      }
    });

    $('.header-logo').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': 0
      }, 'slow')
      return false;
    });

    $('.header-list a').click(function() {

      var id = $(this).attr('href');
      var position = $(id).offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({
        'scrollTop': position - 80
      }, 900);
      /*
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation(); */
      return false;
    });

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato";
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(11, 173, 198);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.header-logo h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lobster", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.header-logo h2:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.header-left {
  float: left;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

.header-list li {
  float: left;
}

.header-list a {
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}

.header-list a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0BADC6;
}

.top-wrapper {
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/97/7c/2e/977c2e8c480428e79cc15cdffdda95ad.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.avatar {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 180px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

.avatar img:hover {
  /*  UNSURE */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.top-wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-top: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.about-wrapper,
.skill-wrapper,
.project-wrapper,
.contact-wrapper,
.faq-wrapper {
  padding: 80px 0 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  min-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  color: #0BADC6;
  border: 2px dashed #0BADC6;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.about-wrapper p {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

blockquote p {
  text-align: right !important;
}

.skill {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.skill-icon {
  position: relative;
}

.skill-icon p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.skill-icon:hover>p {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.project-wrapper {
  height: 600px;
}

.project img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px outset #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.project img:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 25px #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 25px #ccc;
}

.faq-wrapper {
  color: #5f5d60;
}

#faq-list {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.faq-list-item {
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.faq-list-item h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.faq-list-item span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: 5px;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.answer {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.contact-wrapper {
  height: 600px;
}

.form-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#message {
  height: 100px;
}

.form-wrapper p {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.submit {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background-color: #0BADC6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px #036170;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #036170;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.submit:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.submit:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

footer {
  height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0BADC6;
}

.footer-logo {
  float: left;
}

.footer-logo h3 {
  padding-top: 26px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.footer-icons {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 26px;
}

.footer-icons a {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}

.footer-icons a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.menu-icon {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: none;
}


/* Responsive */

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .top-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .avatar img {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .top-wrapper {
    height: 400px;
  }
  .skill-wrapper {
    height: 700px;
  }
  .skill {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .project-wrapper {
    height: 700px;
  }
  .project-wrapper img {
    width: 70%;
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 670px) {
  .top-wrapper {
    height: 350px;
  }
  .top-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .avatar img {
    width: 120px;
  }
  .about-wrapper p {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .header-list {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-list.open {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: beige;
  }
  .header-list li {
    display: block;
  }
  /* Menu    */
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  }
  .change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  }
  .project img {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .footer-logo h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .footer-icons a {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-left">
      <div class="header-logo">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>SH</h2>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <div class="menu-icon">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
      <!--
   <span class="fa fa-bars menu-icon"></span>
   -->
      <ul class="header-list">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">Faq</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: So an **open** class with its own properties was added to the header-list and we're toggling it with jQuery. Did I miss anything else?
Thanks though :)
P.S. I'm going to try to make the menu will width hopefully. If I can't, can I comment back for help?

Comment: That is correct.  My example adds an `open` class to the `header-list` and toggles it with jquery as well as convert your vanilla javascript toggling of the `change` class to jquery.  You most likely will be advised to open up a new question regarding any css issues you might have.

Comment: I can't post new question for another hour so I'm asking you here since I'm practicing your technique at first.

I worked on the menu making it look good but the hover over link is broken. I have fixed the menu except for the hover issue. Could you check in codepen?

Comment: Taking a look now.

Comment: Remove `line-height: 80px;` from `.header-list a` and mess with padding there instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the fiddle and here is the working link of the fiddle, let me know. Will it do https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZZEda/?editors=1101

In case you wanna know what I changed and why,

**js**

Here is simple jQuery code for toggle visibility with fade effect (`fadeToggle` is the method for that).

```
/* Menu */
var menuIcon = $('.menu-icon');
  menuIcon.on('click', function(){
    $('.header-list').fadeToggle();
})
```

**css**

I added these CSS rules in your media query `670 breakpoints`. provided a background to be visible on a mobile screen

```
.header-list {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
.header-list li{
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Learning and Working on both your techniques :)

Comment: In your code, I tried to make the menu smaller(smaller menu for mobile as the current menu is too huge) by lowering the font-size of anchors and also height of li and a too. But then the hover applies way up to the top of the link. How to solve that?

Comment: Edit: Hey, I got it. Thanks again